# Load resource as byte array programmaticaly in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

Here the same question for C#: [load resource as byte array programmaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487726/load-resource-as-byte-array-programmaticaly)

So I've got a resource (just binary file - user data, dosen't really matter). I need to get a pointer to byte array representing this resource, how to do this ? Resource located in *Resource Files* of vs2010 (win32 console project). I think i need to use `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource` function of winapi.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can add resource files

Comment: Q: I think i need to use FindResource, LoadResource and LockResource?  A: Yup.  Exactly: [How to load a custom binary resource in a VC++ static library as part of a dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240188/how-to-load-a-custom-binary-resource-in-a-vc-static-library-as-part-of-a-dll)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To obtain the byte information of the resource, the first step is to obtain a handle to the resource using [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FindResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then, load the resource using 
[LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Finally, use [LockResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the address of the data and access [SizeofResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) bytes from that point. The following example illustrates the process:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL); // get the handle to the current module (the executable file)
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RESOURCE_ID), RESOURCE_TYPE); // substitute RESOURCE_ID and RESOURCE_TYPE.
HGLOBAL hMemory = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
LPVOID lpAddress = LockResource(hMemory);

char *bytes = new char[dwSize];
memcpy(bytes, lpAddress, dwSize);
```

Error handling is of course omitted for brevity, you should check the return value of each call.

Comment: `GetModuleHandle(NULL); // get the handle to the current module` - That's not what the API returns. It returns a handle to the module that was used to create the process. This fails when the resource is compiled into a DLL (a common scenario, in particular with respect to localization). One solution is outlined under [Accessing the current module’s HINSTANCE from a static library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483).

Answer (score 1):

```
HRSRC src = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
    if (src != NULL) {
        unsigned int myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, src);
        HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, src);

        if (myResourceData != NULL) {
            void* pMyBinaryData = LockResource(myResourceData);

            std::ofstream f("A:\\TestResource.exe", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            f.write((char*)pMyBinaryData, myResourceSize);
            f.close();

            FreeResource(myResourceData);
        }
    }
```