# Get Resource as byte[] C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, embedded-resource

I'm trying to get an image in the resources as a `byte[]` for insertion into a database. The resource is at Resources/CatSeal and is a file called index.jpg.

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487726/load-resource-as-byte-array-programmaticaly), but I'm still having trouble. I'm getting a NullReferenceException on the indicated line. My namespace is `DatabaseConnectionTests`. According to this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292#bookmark-5), under "Access Resources" it should follow this format, which I believe I'm doing:

> MyNameSpace.MyImage.bmp

Here's my code:

```
Stream sourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DatabaseConnectionTests.index.jpg");
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    sourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream); // NullReferenceException here
    seal.SealerImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
sealDatabaseOperations.Insert(seal);
```

How can I resolve this so that my resource image is loaded to a `byte[]`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's not finding your resource.

Try: "DatabaseConnectionTests.Resources.index.jpg"

Set a breakpoint in a class in the same assembly and evaluate this:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

That will list all resource names avail for that assembly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so running that in the debugger returns "DatabaseConnectionTests.Seals.resources", but using "DatabaseConnectionTests.Seals.resources.index.jpg" in `GetManifestResourceStream` still produces a NullReferenceException. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, can I just check that you've changed the jpg files Build Action to  Embedded Resource?