# Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string, byte[])' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

Im trying make an app that copy the favicon.ico to %temp% file, I have the below code:

```
string temp = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temp + "favicon.ico", Properties.Resources.favicon);
```

But I am receiving the error:

`Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string, byte[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Maybe because `Properties.Resources.favicon` isn't a `byte[]`?

Comment: it isnt whats why im here i need helps

Comment: What type is `Properties.Resources.favicon`? Maybe something like `.ToByteArray()` could work

Comment: its like an  room where you drag from desktop to it aplications witch can be runned  by the project

Comment: like **Rafalon** stated, if `Properties.Resources.favicon` is not a `byte[]`, then you *cannot* use it as a parameter for `File.WriteAllBytes(string, byte[])`.  check the type of `Properties.Resources.favicon`.

Comment: The Properties.Resources list won't get your files as binary unless you specify them to on the "favicon" file properties. You will have to either change this or load the image from reflection as a Stream then convert to byte[] (you can write the Stream directly with another IO function though). Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487726/load-resource-as-byte-array-programmatically