# Send image to a SOAP 1.0 webservice from a .Net client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to send an image to a SOAP web service implemented in PHP.

The WSDL for the service looks like this...

```
<xsd:complexType name="Product">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="ProductId" type="xsd:int"/>   
    <xsd:element name="Image01" type="xsd:base64Array"/>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When I reference this service in my C# application the data type used for `Image01` is `String`.

How can I get an image from disk and send encode it in the correct way to send it via this complex type?

Would appreciate sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the image up into a `byte[]` type then run it through a `Convert.ToBase64String()`

There's a nice sample of code [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c) to load a file from disk into a byte[]

```
public byte[] StreamToByteArray(string fileName)
{
byte[] total_stream = new byte[0];
using (Stream input = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] stream_array = new byte[0];
    // Setup whatever read size you want (small here for testing)
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];// * 1024];
    int read = 0;

    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stream_array = new byte[total_stream.Length + read];
        total_stream.CopyTo(stream_array, 0);
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, stream_array, total_stream.Length, read);
        total_stream = stream_array;
    }
}
return total_stream;
}
```

So you'd just do

```
Convert.ToBase64String(this.StreamToByteArray("Filename"));
```

And pass that back via the web service call. I've avoided using the `Image.FromFile` call so you can re-use this example with other non image calls to send binary information over a webservice. But if you wish to only ever use an Image then substitute this block of code for an `Image.FromFile()` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to load the Image, transform to Byte[] and convert to Base64

```
Image myImage = Image.FromFile("myimage.bmp");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
myImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] imageByte = stream.ToArray();
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByte);
stream.Dispose();
myImage.Dispose();
```