# how to work with streams? Convert the strem into byte that I receive from the client

Tags: wcf, tcp, stream, byte

I have an async service, and I must transfer a file from the  client to the service. The service is configurated to use the streamed transfer mode, so if I am not wrong, the file is transferred without wait to load all the file.

I would like to know how I can know if the file is finished, because I need to convert this stream to be able to convert this stream into a byte[] to store the file in the database.

i ask this because when I receive the file in the service from the  client, I receive a read only stream, with length property available, and I have problems to convert this stream into the byte array.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your server-side code?

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a memory stream and then readbyte into an array?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataHERE)
byte[] passing = ms.ReadByte();
```