# How to retrieve the posted data (in byte[] format)?

Tags: c#, web-applications, http-post, arrays

I have a C# .net web application. I am trying to post a binary data from one application to another using this code

```
    string url = "path to send the data";

    string result=null;
    string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
    byte[] fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (url);
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.    

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = fileData.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write (fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close ();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.

    result = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    // Display the content.

    result = result + responseFromServer;
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close ();
    dataStream.Close ();
    response.Close();
```

By the above code, I am sending `byte[]` to a second application. How can I retrieve the posted data (in `byte[]` format) in the second application?

Comment: What kind of application is it?

Comment: Its a web application

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I assume that you are asking about how to retrieve the posted data in second application and also you have access to the code of second application.

Then if it is a webform application then simply on page_load event you can get file name and file itself as:

```
string strFileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
HttpPostedFileBase filesToSave = Request.Files[0];
```

If this is not the requirement, then edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Thank you gaurav. From which name space I can get the StringUtility class? Do I need to add any dll and from where?

Comment: sorry my bad.. Please check the updated answer. You can simply get access to the files with indexes. As you are posting 1 file in a request, you can access it with `Request.Files[0]`;

Comment: When I used this code string strFileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
        HttpPostedFile filesToSave = Request.Files[0];  got an error 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: ohh.. and what happens when you try to get it from InputStream as @dblood suggested? Try that and tell what happens.

Comment: I have used this code :    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        Stream stream = context.Request.InputStream; Then in the stream, I am getting the same lenth byte[] which I sent by the above code. Here it is getting as a Stream  obj. How can I convert into byte[]?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c) can help you for this I think.

Comment: Sorry.. I couldn't find Buffer.BlockCopy and Buffer.SetByte in that scope.

Comment: Ok.. then use this method.. it should definitely work.. `public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}`

Comment: You can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221925/creating-a-byte-array-from-a-stream) for more details :)

Comment: And actually you can google for BlockCopy and SetByte methods of System.Buffer.. There is a lot of content on google for these.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Updated answer to include both Request and Server side. Server side converts Base64 string to a `byte[]`.

If you're going to post binary data that was read into a byte[], you'll have to convert it to a Base64 string on request side to post it.

Client/Request Side:

```
byte[] byteData = ReadSomeData();

string postData = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
```

Then on the server side, use the `HttpContext` to get the InputStream from the Request property. You can then use a `StreamReader` and its ReadToEnd() method to read in the data. You then convert the posted Base64 string to a `byte[]`.

Something like this:

```
string postData = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
{
    postData = inputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(postData);
```

Comment: What can be the initialLength, offset and count?

Comment: In reader.Read(buffer, offset, count) the buffer should be the char[] right??

Comment: @Sudha - I updated the answer to be more specific and that I think more clearly answers your question.

Comment: @dblood- When I tried this code got error like : 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.' in byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(postData); line

Comment: Did you Base 64 encode the data on the request side before you posted it as I showed in the example?

Comment: OMG after so many attempts with different ways, finally I find your solution, moreover so simple! Thanks