# System.Security.SecurityException when loading a pdf file to ftp server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I wants to upload pdf files to ftp server. I have written like this.

```
    public void upload_pdf_file(string userName, string password, string test_id, string student_id)
{   

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest rq = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://www.xxx.co/pdf/" + filename + "");
    rq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    rq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    System.IO.Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();
    System.IO.Stream ftpstream = rq.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
}
```

when run this code in local host it works properly.! but when try it on remote host, it shows an error "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."  I have set

```
`   <securityPolicy>
     <trustLevel name="Full"  policyFile="internal"/>
  </securityPolicy> '
```

I have no permission for make any changes on ftp server like " set the application pool to "Load User Profile Wht else to do?? please help

Comment: What have you done to test? Can you manually sFTP a file?

Comment: i have uploaded all my aspx pages to ftp server through filezilla. and run the project with the ftp link @user814064

Comment: There's working code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c

Comment: I can print  fs.length using this code, i have the same problem with when making a folder on ftp . @ user814064