# Convert bitmap to byte[]

Tags: silverlight, bitmap, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am developing a LightSwitch application that generates barcodes (QR images) for tickets. I am calling an encode function that converts text to bitmap.
I just need to save this in an LightSwitch Image field.
I have this:

```
QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
EditableImage image = qrCodeEncoder.Encode(data);
```

I want this:

```
ticket.QRImage = .....???
```

I am using this library for the QR
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/09/quick-read-silverlight-barcodes/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20574/Open-Source-QRCode-Library

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bytes by calling `image.GetStream()`, and then using one of the standard methods to get the bytes out of the stream (see [How to convert an Stream into a byte[] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080442/270348))