# Calculate Content.Length

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting problems making a http POST. The API I am calling is asking for the `content-length`. But I am unsure how to do this.

Here is the code I have:

```
public static string publishClip(string instance_url, string sessionId, string clipId)
{
    int trev = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(instance_url + "/services/apexrest/DesktopClient/PublishClip/" + clipId);

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest
        .Create(instance_url
                + "/services/apexrest/DesktopClient/PublishClip/"
                + clipId);
    wrGETURL.Method = "POST";
    wrGETURL.ContentType = "application/json";
    wrGETURL.ContentLength = trev;
    wrGETURL.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + sessionId);
    Stream objStreamclipId = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStreamclipId);

    return "trev";
}
```

Can anyone help me out please?

This is the error I am getting:

> {"You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse."}

Comment: Please be more specific. It can be clearly seen in your code, that you've tried setting the `ContentLength` property. So, what's the problem? Didn't it work? What's wrong with the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx ?

Comment: In your case the content length is 0, since your request doesn't have a body...

Comment: Did you set the `ContentLength = 0`?

Comment: @BartoszKP apologies, I have now added the error I am getting.

Comment: @christiandev when I set the length to 0 I get "{"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}"

Comment: Regarding your comment under one of the answers: in your case content should be the number of bytes in your URL (what you're doing now seems correct), but then you should also add the URL to the post body, as in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx (I've posted it earlier). Just put your URL for `postData`.

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks. I have read that article but I am still unclear on how to put that code into mine :( sorry. can you help?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Look at christiandev's answer - use it, and put your URL into "postData" variable. Probably leave the encoding part the way you're doing it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
var postData = ?;
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
wrGETURL.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
```

Is your `postData` **Trev**?

Comment: postdata is the url I am calling

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the Bytes from your StreamReader objReader. To do so, see here: [How to convert an Stream into a byte[] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c) and count them.