# convert IO::Stream^ to std::string or char c++

Tags: c++-cli

Is it possible to convert `IO::Stream^` to `std::string` or `char`?

**EDIT**

```
//OpenFileDialog
IO::Stream^ myStream;
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK){
    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr){
        //code
        myStream->Close();
    }
}

//Button
Read(kai, converted_string_or_char); // I need to sent string or char which must be converted from IO::Stream^ myStream;

Write(kai);
richTextBox1->LoadFile("Results.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType::PlainText);

//Reading function
void Read(Sarasas *kai, string converted_string_or_char){
    string name, nr, city;
    int val, min, trukme;
    Abonentas abon;
    ifstream fd(converted_string_or_char);
    while(!fd.eof()){
        getline(fd, name, ',');
        fd >> nr >> city >> val >> min >> trukme;
        abon.Set(name, nr, city, val, min, trukme);
        ab->SetData(abon);
        fd >> ws;
    }
    fd.close();
}
```

Comment: What would this conversion do? How would you expect it to work?

Comment: Sure (trivially, `Convert(x) = "a stream"`), the question is whether it's the conversion that you want. Could you give some example code with outputs?

Comment: I use OpenFileDialog and i have IO::Stream^ myStream; I need to convert it to string or char and use it to reading functions

Comment: That makes no sense at all to me. You need to describe precisely how you wish to convert a stream into a string, and indeed why you would do so. My guess is that you actually wish to use a file dialog to let the user select a file name, and then you wish to read the contents of the file with that name into a string.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194086/open-file-dialog-c)

Comment: FWIW this is not C++, it is C++/CLI

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is encoded as a `std::string` would be (as in, Windows-1252 encoding), you should [read the stream into a managed byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c) and feed a `pin_ptr` to its first byte to `std::string`'s constructor.

If the encodings differ, you should read the file as text (possibly using a `StreamReader` if that helps), then encode the resulting string as Windows-1252 (using `System::Text::Encoding::Default->GetBytes(String^)`) and then use the resulting byte array as above.

**PS:** You should also think on whether it is wise to use a `std::string` rather than an `std::wstring`.