# How can you convert from an Attachment to a byte[]?

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, attachment

I have the next part, which is where I use Microsoft Graph to download an attachment, but I'm at the part where I already get the attachment, but how do I pass that what is returned as an Attachment can be passed to a byte array?

The following is the code used where I obtain the attached files, passing the id of the message and the id of the attached file, and then proceed to download it, but there is a part there that generates an error that is where the method is being used content(), but if I remove it I get an error and I don't know how else I can convert that Attachment to byte[]

```
Attachment attachment = _userClient.me().messages(listIdMessage.get(i)).attachments(idAttachment)
                        .buildRequest()
                        .get();

byte[] fileBytes = attachment.additionalDataManager().
                    InputStream inputStream = _userClient.me().messages(idMessage).attachments(idAttachment).content().buildRequest().get();
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("path/file/" + attachment.name);
                outputStream.write(fileBytes);
                outputStream.close();
```

I just want to somehow download an attachment from an email where on this occasion I use Microsft Graph, if anyone knows a way to convert from Attachment to byte[] with the code I proposed or in another way I would appreciate it.

note: I am using Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

To convert file using the graph api:

```
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content?format={format}
```

For information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example,see

similar question here for the conversion to byte: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219876/mailmessage-attachment-to-byte#:~:text=with%20that%20method%20you%20can%20do%20this%20System.Net.Mail.MailMessage,to%20pull%20it%20back%20out%20of%20the%20database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219876/mailmessage-attachment-to-byte#:%7E:text=with%20that%20method%20you%20can%20do%20this%20System.Net.Mail.MailMessage,to%20pull%20it%20back%20out%20of%20the%20database).