# Is any blocking Read method available for Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, blocking

I am writing an application in C# to open a terminal to a Docker container remotely via a web application. I need to read the stream returned by the Docker.NET client and forward the read bytes via a web socket.

If I call Stream.Read and there is no data available, it simply returns 0 without waiting for data to be available. I spent a while looking for a blocking Read call but couldn't find any. I know .NET has `Console.Read()` which keeps waiting for input in stdin. How does it achieve this blocking call - do they use a loop or is there any blocking method available?

I wrote below code using a while loop and check if any bytes were read. Is it necessary to add Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay to avoid it consuming too much CPU?

```
async Task ForwardStreamViaWebSocket(Stream stream, WebSocket webSocket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var bytesRead = 0;

        // Any blocking Read method available instead of looping?
        while (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Thread.Sleep(100);  // Is this really required?
        }

        var arraySegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        await webSocket.SendAsync(arraySegment, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual `Stream` subclass you're using?

Comment: @Dai Actually the Docker .NET client returns MultiplexedStream which doesn't have any blocking calls. So I will be writing another class to access the Stream within MultiplexedStream. Its hacky but I don't know of any other way.

https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/MultiplexedStream.cs

Comment: Yikes, that's not even a _real_ `Stream` subclass...

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/aacf3c26131f582ca8acc34084663a4b79e28d38/src/Docker.DotNet/MultiplexedStream.cs#L87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream.Read is a blocking call, and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=net-7.0) it should not return unless it either has some data, or reached the end of the stream:

> Read returns 0 only if zero bytes were requested or when there is no more data in the stream **and no more is expected** (such as a closed socket or end of file). An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.

So the sleep should not be needed. However, your code to read data is just wrong, and will only read at most one buffer worth of data. See [How do I convert a Stream into a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-do-i-convert-a-stream-into-a-byte-in-c) to read all of the data from the stream.

Ofc, with third party streams, non-conforming implementations are always possible. So you might want to confirm that all the data are actually read.

Comment: I am streaming the data via a WebSocket. So once 1024 bytes are read and sent via the websocket it will again read the next available bytes as I have a while loop enclosing that code - while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested).

Comment: @SupaCoda Well, your code is still wrong. If you reach the end of the stream you would just get stuck in the `while (bytesRead == 0)`-loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. bytesRead will be 0 on EOF. I will get rid of that while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Read` blocks, it does not consume any CPU. But it does block your thread, preventing anything else being handled. You should really be calling `ReadAsync` anyway, which doesn't block.

Also as mentioned by others, you need to keep forwarding data until the end of the stream. So put `SendAsync` inside the loop.

```cs
async ValueTask ForwardStreamViaWebSocket(Stream stream, WebSocket webSocket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    var mem = buffer.AsMemory();
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = stream.ReadAsync(mem, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(mem.Span.Slice(0, bytesRead), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, false, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```